# OpenGL Translate weird behavior

Tags: opengl, jogl

I'm developing an application in java that uses openGL (JOGL) to draw a pyramid. When I try to make a translation on the pyramid in direction X, what I see, is that my pyramid was translated in direction Z also. Same thing happens when I try to translate the pyramid in direction Y. Translation in direction Z seems to work without problems. What causes this behavior?

Comment: The question cannot be answered as stated. You have a bug in your code, and [without being able to see your code,](http://sscce.org/) we can't say why.

Comment: Thanks for -1 me down, and not being constructive or friendly.

Comment: Alright man, thanks anyway. I just thought that theoretically speaking this is normal behavior. By the way, this comment was constructive. Sorry.

Comment: @bicska88: No problem, you're new here ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour can be caused by many different factors.

You might have:

- Set up your camera wrong (very likely)
- Made matrix transformations, which you didn't reset using `glLoadIdentity` or `glPushMatrix` / `glPopMatrix`.

Comment: I'm looking at the pyramid from (0, 0, 10) and I'm looking at (0, 0, -100), and the normal vector is (0, 1, 0). What could be wrong with it? Im on Z axis in 10, and looking towards the negative end. Please clarify your answer.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know what's wrong. Without the code it's just guessing. But for all I know, JOGL seems to be working just the way it should for such basic operations. As long as we cannot see your code, I think  nobody will give you the answer you're searching.